# Angular pass onclick value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have on array of years links like this:

```
<div class="header-years-container default-color">
              <a class="years-items"  *ngFor="let year of yearsLink;" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedYear === year}" (click)="onSelectYear($event.target.innerText)">
                  {{ year }}
                </a>
            </div>
```

and one property that show data for selectedYear. In ngOnInit method I set default value from array but I want to pass other value of year when user click on that. In Typescript looks this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.yearsLink = [...new Set(this.absenceWidgetService.getAbsencesData().map(item => item.year))];
    this.selectedYear = this.yearsLink[0];


    this.selectedYear = this.onSelectYear(this.selectedYear);
    this.absences = this.absenceWidgetService.getAbsencesData(this.selectedYear)
  }

onSelectYear(value): string {
    return this.selectedYear = value;
  }
```

How can I pass each time correct value for selectedYear in getAbsenceData method when user do click event ? Currently I always have default value..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it like this yet?

HTML:

```
<div class="header-years-container default-color">
    <a class="years-items"  *ngFor="let year of yearsLink;" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedYear === year}" (click)="onSelectYear(year)">
        {{ year }}
    </a>
</div>
```

TS:

```
onSelectYear(year) {
    this.selectedYear = year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$event`, You can directly pass `year` as an argument in function

```
<div class="header-years-container default-color">
     <a class="years-items"  *ngFor="let year of yearsLink;" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedYear === year}" 
     (click)="onSelectYear(year)">{{ year }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It' does not metter.the same thing..don't pass a new value selectedYear only default.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved issue when I moved data source property fill in event method. There is default value in ngOnInit() for this property and for each click event pass a new value.

It looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.yearsLink = [...new Set(this.absenceWidgetService.getAbsencesData().map(item => item.year))];
    this.selectedYear = this.yearsLink[0];

    this.absences = this.absenceWidgetService.getAbsencesData(this.selectedYear)
  }

onSelectYear(year) {
    this.selectedYear = year;
    this.absences = this.absenceWidgetService.getAbsencesData(this.selectedYear);
  }
```